# Can I customise a Fixture in an XUnit constructor for use with Theory and AutoData?

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, autofixture, xunit2

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public class MyTests
{
    private IFixture _fixture;

    public MyTests()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture();
        _fixture.Customize<Thing>(x => x.With(y => y.UserId, 1));
    }

    [Theory, AutoData]
    public void GetThingsByUserId_ShouldReturnThings(IEnumerable<Thing> things)
    {
        things.First().UserId.Should().Be(1);
    }
}
```

I would expect the  `IEnumerable<Thing> things` parameter passed into the test to each have a `UserId` of 1 but this is not what happens.

How can I make this so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by creating a custom `AutoData` attribute derived-type:

```
internal class MyAutoDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    internal MyAutoDataAttribute()
        : base(
            new Fixture().Customize(
                new CompositeCustomization(
                    new MyCustomization())))
    {
    }

    private class MyCustomization : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            fixture.Customize<Thing>(x => x.With(y => y.UserId, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

*You may also add other Customizations. Just keep in mind that [the order matters](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/31/TheorderofAutoFixtureCustomizationsmatter/).*

---

Then, change the test method to use `MyAutoData` attribute instead, as shown below:

```
public class MyTests
{
    [Theory, MyAutoData]
    public void GetThingsByUserId_ShouldReturnThings(IEnumerable<Thing> things)
    {
        things.First().UserId.Should().Be(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could there be a solution, which enables the form Holf posted?
I feel like doing the customization in the ctor has less ceremony,
than creating an attribute and customization classes.
In simple, non-reusable cases it would be nice to have that option too.

Comment: The *form Holf posted*? What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry,
what I mean is the usage pattern assumed in OPs question,
where one could instantiate and customize a fixture in the constructor of a test class,
while still being able to use AutoData on a test method,
which would use the same fixture used in the constructor.

Comment: I had to define the constructor of `MyAutoDataAttribute` public for this to work. Also, replace with function in call to `AutoDataAttribute` constructor like so: `base(() => new Fixture().Customize(new CompositeCustomization(new MyCustomization())))`